# MP3 Player like grooveshark

Tags: php, jquery, html, flash

I am creating a music streaming website like Grooveshark. I have done the coding for uploading the music and creating playlists etc. Now I need to have an audio player for playing the audio files. I like to have one like Grooveshark, which displays at the bottom of the page. I also would like to add icons on the player itself for sharing the song on Facebook etc and a provision for adding it to playlist. Currently I am having the code for displaying songs and playlists etc. What only needed is a player for playing it. Please give me some suggestions.

Regards,
Alwin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try html5 because flash is kind of outdated now-a-days.

For an audio player in html5 you must check out

[Building a custom html5 audio player](http://neutroncreations.com/blog/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-jquery/)

Also check out this tutorial of [Native audio in the browser](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/)

You can also get an html5 audio player from [Codebasehero](http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/)

Comment: I also need a full screen functionality too. that is if someone click on the full screen link,the player has to fill the screen with the playlists displaying on both sides. Like the one in Gaana.com

Comment: I agree, you should use HTML5 but with Flash fallback for older browsers since a lot of them don't (fully) support HTML5 yet

Comment: @xorinzor Yes you are right about it but still HTML5 is the de facto after flash! And there are some workarounds for making it work on older browsers.